# How do I plot the frequency response of a digital filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to graph the frequency response. I was asked to use `filter` in MATLAB, but since I've read the manual, I still don't get how it performs a `Z` transform.

I have the impulse response of the digital filter written below:

```
for i=1:22;
   y(i)= 0;
end
x(22) = 1;
for k=23:2523
    x(k) = 0;
end
for n = 22:2522;
    y(n) = ((1/21)*x(n))+((20/21)*y(n-21));
end
plot(y);
```

It's just a feedback system of `y[n] = 1/21*x[n] + 20/21*y[n-21]`

Below are my calculations to compute the `Z` transform of the above system, which ultimately determines the impulse response:

```
Z(y) = Z((1/21)*x(n)+(20/21)*y(n-21))

Y(Z) = (1/21)X(Z)+(20/21)*Z.^-21Y(Z)

Z(Z)-(20/21)*Z.^-21Y(Z) = (1/21)X(Z)

Y(Z)(1-(20/21)*Z.^-21) = (1/21)X(Z)  // divide by X(Z)*(1-(20/21)*Z.^-21)

Y(Z)/X(Z) = (1/21)/(1-(20/21)*Z.^-21)

H(Z) = (1/21)/(1-(20/21)*Z.^-21) // B = 1/21, A = 20/21

H(Z) = (B*Z.^21)/(Z.^21-A)
```

How can I plot the frequency response of `H(Z)`?  Should I use `filter`?

Comment: Btw, forgot to mention that this function is for first 2500 terms, thats why n is 2500. I used 22 as a start point

Comment: As far as I know, filter does use `s`, not `z`. So you cannot graph it using `z`. If you want to plot the output, why dont you just iterate?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I need to graph the impulse response. How can you use filter with s? what is the difference?

Comment: The difference between the Laplace transform and the Z transform? I had a 6 months undergraduate course in that, nobody will be able to explain it in a stackoverflow answwer!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Oh, but I only need Z transform

Comment: Reformulate your question. you already have a Z transform (the discrete transfer function) and you are already plotting its response.

Comment: Are you trying to plot the **frequency** response or the **impulse response** of `y`?  They are two different things.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry, I need to plot the frequency response of its filter

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov - Thanks mate!  Thanks for accepting my answer here too, but FWIW, I think SleuthEye's answer is what you're looking for as you were asked to use `filter`... but nevertheless, `freqz` is using `filter` combined with a `fft` call under the hood.  BTW, make sure you go through your other questions and if any one else has helped you, make sure you accept their answers too.  It gives them a bit of a reputation increase, and you as well :) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matlab's [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) documentation:

> filters the input data, x, using a [rational transfer function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buagwwg-2) defined by the numerator and denominator coefficients b and a, respectively.

As you might know, filtering an impulse input would give you the impulse response. It then remains to obtain those `b` and `a` coefficients.
You could either obtain those directly from the difference equation

```
y[n] = 1/21*x[n] + 20/21*y[n-21];
```

(as indicated in the [rational transfer function link above](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buagwwg-2)) or equivalently from the rational transfer function you have derived:

```
%H(Z) = (B*Z.^21)/(Z.^21-A)
```

In either case, you should get the following `a` and `b` coefficients:

```
a = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -20/21];
% or equivalently: a=zeros(22,1); a(1)=1; a(22)=-20/21;
b = [1/21];
```

Thus,

```
% setup the impulse input
x = zeros(2500,1);
x(1) = 1;

% compute the impulse response
y = filter(b, a, x);
```

This impulse response can be plotted as you have done:

```
plot(y);
```

As far as how this related to the transform `H(Z)`, the closed form expression you obtained can be evaluated in terms of a [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) expansion, which then has the coefficients of the time-domain `y` (impulse response) series.

However, `H(z)` is an analytic function defined in the `|z| > R` (where `R=power(20/21,1/21)` in your case) region of convergence in the complex plane. It is more typical to plot the frequency response, which corresponds to the `H(z)` evaluated on the unit-circle (i.e. for complex number satisfying `|z|=1` or equivalently `z = exp(j * theta)` with theta in the [0-2pi] range). An efficient method to compute values of `H(z)` at regularly spaced points on that unit-circle is to take the FFT of the impulse response:

```
FrequencyResponse = fft(y);
figure(1);
plot(abs(FrequencyResponse));
figure(2);
plot(phase(FrequencyResponse));
```

*P.S.*: the computation of `filter` and `fft` can be done in the single call `freqz` if you have the signal processing toolbox (although you were specifically asked to use `filter`).

Comment: This is most likely what the OP is after as `filter` is required.  +1.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to plot the impulse response it's easy. The impulse response is the response of the digital filter to a Dirac pulse. You already have the difference equation, so you're already in 'z' and you don't care about the 's', you don't have to perform the 's' to 'z' transform (which is a topic in itself!).

So just generate a signal x(n) consisting of zeros everywhere except the first sample x(1) being 1. Pass it through the filter (yes, your difference equation). The y(n) you get is your impulse response h(n). That's basically what you did.

And of course if you FFT this h(n) you get the phase and magnitude response.

Comment: Thanks! And how can I get and plot the filter of that system?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) from the signal processing toolbox (hope you have it).  You first need to find the Z-transform, which you have already done here:

```
Y(Z)/X(Z) = (1/21)/(1-(20/21)*Z.^-21)
```

`freqz` takes in a vector of coefficients which correspond to the numerator and denominator of your transfer function.  It's called like so:

```
freqz(b, a);
```

`b` and `a` are the numerator and denominator coefficients of your transfer function.  This will produce a figure that shows the magnitude and phase response (hence frequency response) of the above system.

Therefore, all you need is to do this:

```
b = 1/21;
a = [1 zeros(1,20) -(20/21)];
freqz(b, a)
```

Take special note of the `a` vector.  It has 1, followed by 20 zeros, then followed by `-(20/21)`.  Because you have a coefficient to the power of -21 and nothing else other than the 1 before it, that means that those coefficients between -1 to -20 are **zero**, and there are 20 of these coefficients that are zero in total, which is why we need to fill in the vector with zeroes between the 1 and `-(20/21)` term.

We get:

[image]

---

If you want to plot the poles and zeroes of your filter, use a combination of [`tf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) and [`pzmap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pzmap.html):

```
sys = tf(b, a, -1);
pzmap(sys);
```

`tf` creates a transfer function by specifying the numerator and denominator coefficients of your filter, and `-1` implies it's a discrete-time filter, but we don't know what the sampling time is.  `pzmap` plots the poles and zeroes in the z-domain with the unit-circle overlaid.

We get this:

[image]

This makes sense as you have no zeroes in your system, and 21 poles, as you have 21 delay elements when examining the discrete-time sequence in your example.

Comment: thanks! Btw, to find poles and zeros, should I firstly find the roots of the filter and then plot on a complex domain graph? 
r = roots(y); zplane(r);

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov - There you go.  Have fun!